# How to get multiple image file infos using promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, promise, dimensions

I am Using promise to get dimensions of multi uploaded image files.
This is what I tried but I got empty array.

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

Javascript file

```
$('input').change(function() {

    var filereaders = [];
    var dimensions = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
        filereaders[i] = new FileReader;
        filereaders[i].onload = function() {
          var img = new Image;

          dimensions[i] = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            img.onload = function() {
                    resolve(img.width)
            };
          })      
          img.src = this.result;
        } 

        filereaders[i].readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
      }

      Promise.all(filereaders).then(function(res){
          Promise.all(dimensions).then(function(dims){
            console.log(dims) // [] array,I expect [23,434,123]...
          }).catch(function(errdims){
            console.log(errdims)
          })
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
      })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Promise.all(filereaders)
```

`filereaders` is an array of FileReader instances, not an array of Promises. Calling `Promise.all` on this array will immediately resolve the Promise, *before* any `fileReader.onload` event handlers have fired. Therefore, the `dimensions` array is still empty at this point. Now we get to `Promise.all(dimensions)`, and it's an empty array.

For your first `Promise.all` call, you could wrap your FileReaders in Promises and resolve them `onload`:

```
var filereaders = []
for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
  var file = this.files[i]
  filereaders.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader;
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      var img = new Image;

      dimensions[i] = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        img.onload = function() {
          resolve(img.width)
        };
      })      
      img.src = this.result;

      resolve();
    } 

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }))
}
```

Now, `filereaders` is an array of Promises, so you can use `Promise.all` on it.

There are some other things that could be done to simplify this code, though. `File` objects in JavaScript are `Blob`s, and [Blobs can be added as Image `.src`s without first reading them with a FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images). Use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL):

```
var dimensions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
  var file = this.files[i];
  dimensions.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function () {
      resolve(img.width);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(src);
    };
    img.src = src;
  }));
}
```

Now we only need to wait for `Promise.all(dimensions)`, and we can forget about `filereaders` entirely.

```
Promise.all(dimensions).then(function(dims){
  console.log(dims) // [] array,I expect [23,434,123]...
}).catch(function(errdims){
  console.log(errdims)
})
```

Comment: Btw, your first example returns [] still now :)

Comment: Oh! Yeah, I made a mistake in the first example which was causing the `FileReader` to always fail. I think I fixed it, good that the second one worked \o/